# Update Database On Button Press Not CheckBox Check

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I seem to be stuck with tunnel vision only seeing how to update a database based off the check/uncheck event of a checkbox.  What I am wanting to do is hold the event from firing until a button is pressed.  How could I achieve such?

**HTML**

```
<td valign="top" style="text-align: left; width: 200px;">
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="datagridTest" AutoGenerateColumns="false" GridLines="Both" >
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="thirteen" HeaderText="You" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="seven" HeaderText="Me" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("josemen1212") %>' ID="red" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="checker" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="Checker_Click" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("green")) %>' />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
</br>
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClickMe" CssClass="Buttons" Text="Click" OnClick="btnClickMe_Click" />
</td>
```

**C#**

```
private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Here is where I want the update to run
}

protected void Checker_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach (GridViewRow row in dgRD.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checker");
        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            string ID = ((Label)row.FindControl("josemen1212")).Text;
            //Run Sql statement to update db
        }
        else
        {
            string ID = ((Label)row.FindControl("josemen1212")).Text;
            //Run sql statement to update db
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You just need to move your code from `Checker_Click` to `btnClickMe_Click` right? Or is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Just remove the code in your Checker_Click event and put it in your btnClickMe_Click event. Then remove the call to Checker_Click from the checkbox itself.

Comment: @Gilgamesh & sr28 - do I have a need for the Checker_click method anymore?

Comment: no, you don't need the `Checker_click` method anymore

Comment: May I ask what is the use of `string ID` in your `if (chk.Checked)` block? and why the `string ID` is identical? That is, both obtained from `((Label)row.FindControl("josemen1212")).Text;` does that make any difference?

Comment: @Ian - trying to capture the ID of the row that is being selected in order to run an update statement.  Can I capture that value only once outside of the if/else block?

Comment: @RashidInman exactly. Since they are identical, you can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the code from the `Checker_Click` method to the `btnClickMe_Click` event?
Something like this:

```
 private void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      foreach (GridViewRow row in dgRD.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)row.FindControl("checker");
            if (chk.Checked)
            {
                string ID = ((Label)row.FindControl("josemen1212")).Text;
                //Run Sql statement to update db
            }
            else
            {
                string ID = ((Label)row.FindControl("josemen1212")).Text;
                //Run sql statement to update db
            }
        }
    }
    }
```